# how to combine two text documents

Tags: python-2.7

hello im been unable to find the exact answer to my problem.

i need to combine two text documents in this way please see example.

text document 1

sugar,
coffee,
water,
house,

text document 2

asucar,
cafe,
agua,
casa,

i need to combine it like this it needs to be in a decending list.

sugar
asucar
coffee
cafe
water
agua
house
casa

thats all . easy right??

Thank you in advance... i have look around there its lots about how to cpmbine to list but none exactly like this.

Comment: What did you try? And what do you call a 'descending' list here?

Answer (score 0):

If you split the words of the documents into two arrays (based on spaces) then you would be able to loop through both of the arrays at once, adding one word after the other. For example:

```
public String combineDocuments(String[] firstDocument, String[] secondDocument) {
  StringBuilder newDocument = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < firstDocument.length && i < secondDocument.length; i++) {
    newDocument.append(firstDocument[i]);
    newDocument.append(" ");
    newDocument.append(secondDocument[i]);
  }
  return newDocument.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the text files, split them (by comma, tab or any other character), then just join them:

```
#read the text files
with open("data1.txt") as myfile:
   data1_txt="".join(line.rstrip() for line in myfile)
with open("data2.txt") as myfile:
   data2_txt="".join(line.rstrip() for line in myfile)

#get the data
data1=data1_txt.split(',')
data2=data2_txt.split(',')

#join the data
joined = [(data1[i],data2[i]) for i in range(len(data1)]

#now sort it
joinedSorted = sorted(joined,reverse=True)
```